# Return a different view than default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, view, controller

This is homework, and I looked up similar questions, but I'm too code-challenged to know exactly how the syntax should be from the examples.  This is an ASP.NET MVC app in Visual Studio, C#.  This is what I get when I run it.
[image]

When I click on "Edit" or "Details" I want it to go to a page where a bike can be edited or details entered.  Right now, it's going to the original assignment's index page, which has nothing to do with this, but the professor wants all of our assignments in one project:

[image: Solution Explorer]

Here is my BikeController code:

```
using MvcApplication3.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class BikeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Bike/

        List<Bike> bikes;


        public BikeController()
        {
            if (bikes == null)
            {
                bikes = new List<Bike> {
                new Bike(),
                new Bike { Manufacturer = "Nishiki", Gears = 5, Frame = "Road" }
            };
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(this.bikes);
        }

        private ActionResult View(Func<object> func)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var currentBikes = bikes[id];
            return View(currentBikes);

        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Bike/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                Bike b = new Bike
                { 
                    Manufacturer = collection["Manufacturer"], Gears = int.Parse(collection["Gears"]), Frame = collection["Frame"]
                };
                bikes.Add(b);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View(bikes.Where(b => b.BikeID == id).First());
        }

        //
        // POST: /Bike/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Bike/Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Bike/Delete/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        public int bike { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the Index in the Bike View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.Bike>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Manufacturer)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gears)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Frame)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufacturer)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gears)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Frame)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.BikeID @item.Manufacturer @item.Gears @item.Frame
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.BikeID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.BikeID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.BikeID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us the cshtml of the index where those links are created

Comment: Sorry, it's there now.

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting your BikeID, this needs to be unique

Also i'm have not sure what this is for

```
public int bike { get; set; }
```

in your BikeController try explicitly setting the id's

```
new Bike() { BikeID =  1},
new Bike { Manufacturer = "Nishiki", Gears = 5, Frame = "Road", BikeID = 2 }
```

Also check your routing, in Global.asax there will

make sure routing is set up, this should be in either your global.asax or App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: This is my Model:

namespace MvcApplication3.Models
{
    public class Bike
    {
        
        public int BikeID { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public int Gears { get; set; }
        public string Frame { get; set; }

        static protected int bikeCount;

        public Bike()
        {
            this.Manufacturer = "Schwinn";
            this.Gears = 10;
            this.Frame = "Mountain";
            this.BikeID = bikeCount;
            bikeCount++;
        }
    }

}

Comment: Okay this is not a good way to create the index's as each time you call an action the int bike will increase. and this will give you different Id's everytime. Try and explictly setting the id's for now.

Comment: what is the Edit url on the index page in the browser? it should be something like /Bike/Edit/1

Comment: http://localhost:6045/?action=Edit&controller=Bike&id=0 when I click on Edit for Schwinn.

Comment: There are two things wrong with that, the most important is that id=0, this should be id=1 (if you explicitly set the BikeID  )
Number 2, it looks as if your routing may not be set up, i will update the answer

Comment: Do any of your comments resolve the issue, "When I click on 'Edit' or 'Details' I want it to go to a page where a bike can be edited or details entered. Right now, it's going to the original assignment's index page, which has nothing to do with this, but the professor wants all of our assignments in one project"?